# Mouse scroll with tween effect [Mootools]

Tags: mootools, tween

I'm trying to do a mouse scroll effect like this:
http://www.s5-style.com/#!/works (ClientWorks)

But my problem is, mootools dont have a good class Tween for do this.
Then, i have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/FU9Hp/

```
$('content').addEvent('mousemove', function(event)
{
        var padding = this.getPosition();
        var size =  this.getSize();
        var scrollpos =  this.getScroll();
        var scrollsize =  this.getScrollSize();
        var mouseX = (event.client.x-padding.x);

        var percent = Math.round(mouseX*100/(size.x));
        var scrollWidth = (scrollsize.x-size.x);


        this.scrollTo(Math.round(percent*scrollWidth/100), 0);  
});
```

How i can use the class Tween for do the effect of s5-style.com?

Answer (score 2):

> But my problem is, mootools dont have a good class Tween for do this. Then, i have this:

er. mootools has an awesome tween. And it also has Fx.Scroll and Fx.SmoothScroll which bind tweening to scrolling.

Here is an example of a scroll with an elastic transition:
http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/FU9Hp/3/

see http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Scroll and http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.SmoothScroll

Comment: Fx.Tween dont have a onfinish event or onupdate. It is very limited for this.

I changed the the transition for Quad.easeIn. But dont work correctly, have a bit delay in the response of the mouse.

Comment: it has `onComplete`, `onStart`, etc events as it inherits from Fx